# Regular expression acting weird?

Tags: javascript, regex

if I have:

```
var invalidCharacters = /[-+e.]/i;
```

and

```
if(invalidCharacters.test(document.getElementById("postCode").value)) {
  var error_cardNo ="Please only use numbers in your post code.";
  document.getElementById("formTital").innerHTML=error_cardNo; 
  console.log("Test for invalidCharacters was true in cardNo");
  return;
}
```

I then enter any input with  a "+", and it gets a pass, despite

```
var invalidCharacters = /[-+e.]/i;
```

The test is true if the input has "-", "e" and "." , why not "+"?

Why do I not get a true on the test if my input has a +, and how do I fix it so I do get a true? This scenario is the same for several validations throughout my code. Let me know if you need the full function!

(have mercy I'm new)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: make sure your plus is not unicode ＋

Comment: Try `console.log`ing `document.getElementById("postCode").value`

Comment: What do you mean by unicode @YOU ?

Comment: He meant that + and ＋ are two different characters.

Comment: [Here](https://regex101.com/r/mC8aS4/1) you can test your Regex against input. As you can see, the problem cannot be reproduced as you stated it.

Comment: Given that we can't reproduce the problem from the code shown, can you perhaps include a link to a demo at http://jsfiddle.net that is a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: It's probably also good practise to backslash a - in a character class so that it's not accidently used for a range of characters. Hence [\-+e.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, I understand that you can not reproduce the problem from the code shown. However, the problem itself was still there (For whatever unknown reason).

However, for anyone who has the same problem as me, try setting the input giving you woe to text NOT numbers. There seems to be something letting - + pass when the input is number type.

Doing this fixed my code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: A number cannot have a `+` in it. Numbers don't have digits, or even base. Numbers just have quantity. A literal in code is a string representation of a number, just like a program file is a string saved to the disk. When a literal is parsed, it is a true number: the plus is not there any more. When you invoke `RegExp.test` on a number, it is actually being auto-cast to string, a sequence of numbers. So `+18.000` in code becomes just the quantity of eighteen, which when autocast to string becomes `"18"`.

Comment: That said, a `value` of a textfield will always be a string, not a number, so it is not reproducible in the code sample you gave us.